# Python memory increases despite garbage collection

Tags: python, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm trying to count the occurrence of a large corpus of words in a large pool of documents using multiple threads in a MapReduce-like fashion. Each thread starts with a dictionary mapping every word in the corpus to zero and increments the counts as it goes over the documents. Once all threads are done I want to accumulate the counts. I load the first json file into memory and loop through the rest, summing the counts:

```
def merge_counts(self):
    path = os.path.join(self.get_current_job_directory(), 'batch_0.json') 
    with open (path, 'r') as json_file:
        kmers = json.load(json_file)
    batch = None
    for i in range(1, self.num_threads):
        path = os.path.join(self.get_current_job_directory(), 'batch_' + str(i) + '.json') 
        with open (path, 'r') as json_file:
            batch = json.load(json_file)
            for kmer in batch:
                kmers[kmer] += batch[kmer]
        batch = None
    return kmers
```

Here `kmers` is the eventual dictionary containing all the final counts. The number of keys inside `kmers` remains the same no matter how many batches are load as they all have the same keys only with different counts. Each json file is approx 3 gig large so the final result will also be around the same. I'm expecting this code to use as much memory as holding two such json files in memory (the consensus so far and the current batch) as dictionaries but the memory usage grows linearly with each batch until I eventually run out of memory. Why is that happening? Isn't the previous stuff referenced by the variable `batch` supposed to be garbage collected when I set it to `None`?

**Update:** So I added `gc.collect()` at the end of each loop iteration and the memory still grows linearly with each iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to force garbage collection? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316793/1042144

Comment: @BrianKung That really helped stopping the linear growth but the memory usage still increases over time.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not particularly good at memory management, and Python isn't my primary language. Maybe get some instrumentation around it and then look up memory optimization techniques in Python. Good luck!

Comment: It will be helpful to know why question has been downvoted so that I can increase my chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have figured this out by now, but I have encountered a similar problem recently and I had a hard time finding answers. So posting my solution here for a record.

It seems `json.load()` (or `loads()` for that matter) on large files seems to prevent `batch` from being garbage collected due to some references, so you get major memory leaks.

However making `batch` a deepcopy of the json.load() seemed to allow python to run garbage collection properly. So:

```
import copy
...
batch = copy.deepcopy(json.load(json_file))
...
gc.collect()
```

Haven't had time to look into why this happens, but seems to be working in my case.